# How to generate random date in specific format in a cell using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

My piece of code is like below

```
Dim num As Integer
Dim dblRandBetween  As Double

Dim startDate As Date, endDate As Date
startDate = "1/1/1990"
endDate = "1/1/2012"
num = InputBox("How Many IC numbers need to be generated")

For i = 1 To num
        Set curCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3)
    dblRandBetween = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(startDate, endDate)
    ActiveCell.Value = dblRandBetween
    ActiveCell.Value.NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

Next i
```

Am hitting "Run time error: 438" : Object doesnt support this property or method.

Comment: Which line throws this error?

Comment: Sorry I didn't know how I can find. When I fetched error detail using OnError function I got line no as "0"

Comment: You should run the macro from the Visual Basic Editor and when the error appears there will be a "yellow line" (where the code stops because of an error detection)

Comment: Maybe it's Excel 2003 or earlier, no `RandBetween` there

Answer (score 2):

Is this as simple as changing:

```
ActiveCell.Value.NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"
```

to

```
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"
```

As the numberformat must be applied to the active cell not value.

Maybe try the full edit as below:

```
Dim num As Integer
Dim dblRandBetween  As Double
Dim startDate As Date, endDate As Date

startDate = "1/1/1990"
endDate = "1/1/2012"
num = InputBox("How Many IC numbers need to be generated")

For i = 1 To num
    dblRandBetween = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(startDate, endDate)
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3)
        .Value = dblRandBetween
        .NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: Still am getting the same error even though I have changed the number format code

Comment: I have eddited the code in full and tests OK for me (with simple and long change). Please try and see.

Comment: Still getting same error after using the above code :(

Comment: I guess randbetween is not applicable in excel 2003. Need to find an alternative for random date generation now

Comment: if you comment out the randbetween line the code works ok?

Comment: If the issue is with the RandBetween, test it on the actual worksheet... adding the ATP (analysis toolpack for Excel) should fix the issue.